# wx.Grid cell size lock

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wx.Grid to build spreadsheetlike input interface. I want to lock the size of the cells so the user can not change them. I have successfully disabled the drag-sizing with `grid.EnableDragGridSize(False)` of the grid but user can still resize the cells by using borders between column and row labels. I am probably missing something in `wxGrid` documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To completely lock user ability to resize cells it is needed to use `.EnableDragGridSize(False)` , `.DisableDragColSize()` and `.DisableDragRowSize()`  methods.